# Add a loop (foreach) on the taxonomy

Tags: views, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy of devices, I want to add a loop so that when you add new items in the taxonomy came out in the corresponding content:
[image]

I don't know how exactly to implement, but thought something like this code:

```
<?php foreach ($childTaxonomiesArray as $taxonomy): ?>
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <?php print render($taxonomy->field_image); ?>
       <?php print render($taxonomy->title); ?>
         </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

could not tell what to write in foreach order to capture the picture and the caption under the categories...
For clarity, you can see the site itself: http://shifonur.2d.uz/medicina

Comment: Why don't you try the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module for that?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan I used view to output the taxonomy on the left block... to be honest I don't quite understand Your question

Comment: @KrishnaMohan maybe add taxonomy_get_children?